# HTTPS request via urllib2 fails behind NTLM proxy

Tags: python, https, urllib2, monkeypatching

Via Python's `urllib2` I try to get data over HTTPS while I am behind a corporate NTLM proxy.

I run

```
proxy_url = ('http://user:pw@ntlmproxy:port/')
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy_url})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

f = urllib2.urlopen('https://httpbin.org/ip')
myfile = f.read()
print myfile
```

but I get as error

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507: 
EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
```

How can I fix this error?

**Note 0:** With the same code I can retrieve the unsecured HTTP equivalent [`http://httpbin.org/ip`](http://httpbin.org/ip).

**Note 1:** From a normal browser I can access [`https://httpbin.org/ip`](https://httpbin.org/ip) (and other HTTPS sites) via the same corporate proxy.

**Note 2:** I was reading about many similar issues on the net and some suggested that it might be related to *certificate verification*, but `urllib2` does **not** verify certificates anyway.

**Note 3:** Some people suggested in similar situations *monekypatching*, but I guess, there is no way  to monkeypatch `_ssl.c`.

Comment: Check [python-ntlm](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/) from google. Might help !

Comment: Looks like according to this: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/242 , ntlm proxy authentication is not yet available for python modules.

Comment: @pavel_form I can retrieve the unsecured HTTP equivalent [`http://httpbin.org/ip`](http://httpbin.org/ip) in the same manner. Why does the NTLM authentication works for HTTP but not for HTTPS?

Comment: Solution using COM objects that I posted in a related thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/630884/forward-ntlm-authentication-to-corporate-proxy-from-local-proxy-server/755936#755936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Python's standard HTTP libraries do not speak Microsoft's proprietary NTLM authentication protocol fully.

I solved this problem by setting up a local NTLM-capable proxy - [`ntlmaps`](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) did the trick for me.(*) - *which providesthe authentication against the corporate proxy* and point my python code to this local proxy without authentication credentials.

Additionally I had to add in the above listed python code a proxy_handler for HTTPS. So I replaced the two lines

```
proxy_url = 'http://user:pw@ntlmproxy:port/' 
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy_url})
```

with the two lines

```
proxy_url = 'http://localproxy:localport/' 
proxy_url_https = 'https://localproxy:localport/' 
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy_url, 'https': proxy_url_https})
```

Then the request works perfectly.

---

(*) `ntlmaps` is a Python program. Due to some reasons in my personal environment it was for me  necessary that the proxy is a python program.)