# When using any web request lib in python the response times out on my corporate PC but not my personal?

Tags: python, ip, urllib, firewall

I am new to python, but I am having trouble replicating something that works on my personal PC.

For example this works on my personal PC but not on my work one:

```
import urllib.request
contents = urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
print(contents)
```

when doing ipconfig on my work PC I see:

```
Connection-Specific Suffix..............url
Link Local IPv6 Address.................Ipv6 code
IPv4 Address............................ip address1
Subnet Mask.............................ip address2
default gateway.........................ip address3
```

Where the words here are different ip's etc.

Is there something I have to do to direct my web request in a specific way via one of these ip's etc?

(Extra info)

In VBA on the same machine, xmlhttprequests work but winhttp5.1 requests dont, also the ping command and pip commands also time out in my command window (this info may help it may not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [this is a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881718/https-request-via-urllib2-fails-behind-ntlm-proxy); `urllib`, among others, cannot negotiate Corporate NTLM proxies. You can get around this by setting up your own NTLM capable proxy on your machine using [`ntlmaps`](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/).

Your python program can then talk via your proxy like so:

```
import urllib2

proxy_url = 'http://localproxy:localport/' 
proxy_url_https = 'https://localproxy:localport/' 
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy_url, 'https': proxy_url_https})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

f = urllib2.urlopen('https://httpbin.org/ip')
myfile = f.read()
print myfile
```